# What is the default content type for custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

What is the default content type for custom list in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Name or ID or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be `Item`, ID is `0x01`. For a complete list of the OOTB Content Types, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms452896(v=office.14).aspx